# Selenium in Java: No such element error since web page is not loaded yet

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, bdd

I'm trying to do automation on Amazon. After I search "laptop" on Amazon, I try to select "Apple" brand but I recieve no such element error. When I inspect the element manually, I see it is located like this:

`<span class="a-size-base a-color-base">Apple</span>`

My xpath: `//span[class='a-size-base a-color-base' and text()='Apple'][1]`

I want to select this element:

[image]

But when I debug before clicking for brand, I see this:

[image: element_while_debug]

I see the webpage is not loaded fully yet. But I added explicit wait in my code.

Here is my code:

```
import static driver.DriverFactory.getDriver;

public class SearchItem {
    private WebDriver driver = getDriver();

    private WebDriverWait waiter() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        return wait;
    }

    @Given("I am on amazon.com")
    public void i_am_on_the_amazon_com() {
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
    }

    @When("I search {string}")
    public void i_search(String item) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys(item);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-button")).click();
    }

    @And("I select Apple brand")
    public void i_select_Apple_brand() {
        waiter().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[class='a-size-base a-color-base' and text()='Apple'][1]"))).click();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add "@" before "class". So ```//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-base' and text()='Apple'][1]``` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because classes are separated by space. And you give it two classes. You need to give it only one in that syntax of xpath. (By the way, why not use css selector and give multiple classes).

`//span[@class='a-size-base' and text()='Apple'][1]`

Comment: I tried with the above xpath but received the same error. Also, with css selector, I think I still have to find a way to select the web element that contains the inner text 'Apple'. And it seems there is no way to do that like with xpaths.

Comment: Which version of xpath are you using? Maybe And statement is not in your version. Also, add to your question the element you want to select.

Comment: I think I'm using version 1.0. Also I added the element I want to select in my question.

Comment: Ho I think I got the problem, the way of specify the class is @class. Also I meant that you show the html of the element you want to select.

Comment: Yes, I just realized @class too. Thanks anyway!